# Calling django methods from a twisted server

Tags: django, twisted

Consider this problem, in a parent directory there are two (2) directories. In one directory is the root for a django server whilst another directory is the root for a twisted server. The twisted server receives data, whilst the django server serves data to a website and manages a database.

```
|-root- django   -|
                  |-manage.py
                  |-site/
      - twisted  -|
                  |-server.py
```

I want the twisted server to be able to supply data to models in the django site, however, I am getting the following error when simply calling the methods.

**You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.**

Which is the best workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

To do [exactly what it tells you to](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/).

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=yoursite.settings
```

...

```
setup_environ(settings)
```

...

```
settings.configure(...)
```